Prove a surjective endomorphism $\phi$ of a 1-relator group $ ⟨a, b ∣ a^{-1} b^2 a b^{-3}⟩ $ is not injective
Consider the infinite group $H$ with presentation
$$
⟨a, b ∣ a^{-1} b^2 a b^{-3}⟩
$$
so that the relation is $a^{-1} b^2 a=b^3$.
The map
$$
a ↦ a\\b ↦ b^2
$$
induces a surjective homomorphism $ϕ:H\to H$ by Von Dyck's theorem, since $ϕ(a^{-1}b^2ab^{-3})=a^{-1}b^4ab^{-6}=(a^{-1}b^2a)^2(b^{-3})^2=e$.
Check $ϕ$ is surjective: $a=ϕ(a),b=ϕ(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)$.
How to prove $ϕ$ is not injective?
So I need write down a reduced word in $a, b$, not a product of conjugates of powers of the relator $a^{-1} b^2 a b^{-3}$, that is in the kernel of $ϕ$.

I tried $ϕ((b^{-1}a^{-1} ba)(b^{-1}a^{-1} b a)b^{-1})=bbb^{-2}=e$.
How to prove $b^{-1}a^{-1} bab^{-1}a^{-1} b ab^{-1}$ is not a product of conjugates of powers of the relator $a^{-1} b^2 a b^{-3}$?

The Baumslag-Solitar group
$$\text{BS}(m,n)=\langle a,b\mid a^{-1}b^mab^{-n}\rangle=\langle a,b\mid ab^na^{-1}b^{-m}\rangle$$
is the HNN-extension of $\Bbb Z=\langle b\mid ~\rangle$ by the isomorphism $\alpha:n\Bbb Z\to m\Bbb Z,\;nk\mapsto mk$.
Let
$$w=b^{k_0}a^{\varepsilon_1}b^{k_1}a^{\varepsilon_2}\dots b^{k_{r-1}}a^{\varepsilon_r}b^{k_r}\in\text{BS}(m,n), \qquad r>0,k_i\in\Bbb Z,\varepsilon_i= \pm 1.$$
By Britton's lemma, if $w=1$ then $m$ or $n$ divides some $k_i$.
This is not the case for your element $b^{-1}a^{-1} bab^{-1}a^{-1} b ab^{-1}\in\text{BS}(2,3)$ of $\ker\phi$. Hence $\phi$ is not injective.

Outstanding, thank you!
